# Azure Function beta/v2 - Integration Dependensies - SQL/MySql

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm using the beta version of the Azure Functions because I'm using the Graph API and I would like to connect a database (MySQL/SQL).

Just using the latest **beta version/v2** with the following [guide from Microsoft](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal.md) to connect a SQL Database I get an error.

I know that there are a few differences regarding the [integration of the dependencies](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/136). I mean the use and the structure of the file "`project.json`" instead of "`function.proj`"

What I have to do to make it work?

This is the returned error. I remind that it's with the beta version because in my real project I use the Graph Api as well:

```
2018-08-08T06:43:59  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2018-08-08T06:44:06.613 [Information] Executing 'Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=a3eb2b63-b336-4f56-bc3e-a1862b8f2d06)
2018-08-08T06:44:06.671 [Information] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 8/8/2018 6:44:06 AM
2018-08-08T06:44:06.786 [Error] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. f-TimerTriggerCSharp1__-1020707796: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2018-08-08T06:44:06.906 [Error] Executed 'Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1' (Failed, Id=a3eb2b63-b336-4f56-bc3e-a1862b8f2d06)
2018-08-08T06:45:07.294 [Information] Executing 'Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1' (Reason='Timer fired at 2018-08-08T06:45:07.2936684+00:00', Id=2a28db1e-f70f-4919-b7c9-078d39fb12a6)
2018-08-08T06:45:07.300 [Information] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 8/8/2018 6:45:07 AM
2018-08-08T06:45:07.303 [Error] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. f-TimerTriggerCSharp1__-1020707796: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2018-08-08T06:45:07.893 [Error] Executed 'Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1' (Failed, Id=2a28db1e-f70f-4919-b7c9-078d39fb12a6)
```

This instead is my "run.csx" file:

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"


using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        conn.Open();
        //Just a test
        var text = "UPDATE Persons SET FirstName = 'Alfred Schmidt', LastName= 'Frankfurt'";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
            //var rows = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            //log.Info($"{rows} rows were updated");
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I'm trying to connect a MySQL database instead of a SQL and I get the following error:

```
2018-08-08T12:54:46.569 [Error] run.csx(15,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

These are my dependencies:

```
#r "System.Configuration" 
#r "System.Data" 
using System; 
using System.Configuration; 
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_MySqlConnection");
```

Comment: Please share the error message you have received

Comment: The link you posted for the "guide from Microsoft to connect a SQL database" is just a link to create a SQL database in the Azure Portal. Is this what you meant to post? +1 to error message too!

Comment: Hi Alberto, Hi Marie, 
Many thanks for your reply.
I added copy of the code so you can give me a better support. The code is exactly that one in the Microsoft example but I'm using the beta version of the Azure Functions because in my real project I need to use also the Graph Api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConfigurationManager is no longer supported in v2 function, see this [relate comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/328#issuecomment-355697529).

> In 2.0, we have moved to the new ASP.NET Core configuration model. We intend to support binding to an IConfiguration instance that will provide a similar API, but in the meantime, the workaround is to read environment variables as opposed to relying on the ConfigurationManager and its APIs.

So you could use following statement to get connection string. Prefix `SQLAZURECONNSTR_` is added by Azure for SQLAzure connection string set under Connection strings part.

```
var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_SqlConnection");
```

**Update** for MySql Connection

Go to `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`, it shows content of function app. Right click on your function folder, New file, create `function.proj` as below. Adding this dependency file imports related assembly for you to reference.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.12" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hi Jerry,
Many thanks for your prompt reply. It is actually one step forward. :)
However, if I uncomment the following lines to get the resuly from the query to the DB I get the following error:

2018-08-08T09:57:16.506 [Error] run.csx(22,24): error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
How can I fix it?

Comment: @Filippo Just change your method signature to `public static async Task Run`.

Comment: I'm infinitely grateful to you for your help! :D
I spent so much time trying to make it working that you can't even imagine. There is not any good documentation online regarding the beta version.

Comment: @Filippo Not at all, could you accept my answer to close this question?

Comment: Please, only one more question. I'm trying to connect a MySQL database instead of a SQL and I get the following error:

2018-08-08T12:54:46.569 [Error] run.csx(15,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


These are my dependencies:

#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_MySqlConnection");

Thank u in advance!

Comment: @Filippo It's time to use integration of the dependencies you mentioned, see my update.

Comment: Found the solution:
Creation file "function.proj"

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" Version="2.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="7.0.7-m61"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

File "run.csx":

#r "System.Data"

using System;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Comment: @Filippo Great, similar to my suggestion. BTW, I do recommend you to update in question or answers instead of in comment.